# Generate number contains from a list of random number

Tags: vb.net

```
strwords(1) = 1
strwords(2) = 2
strwords(3) = 3
```

How should you use generation? if the random number is 1 or 2 or 3? the Or function does not work in this case.

```
    If randomNumber1 = strWords(1) or strWords(2) or strWords(3) Then
        TxtRndX.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & randomNumber1)
    Else
    End If
```

Comment: The syntax should be `randomNumber1 = strWords(1) Or randomNumber1 = strWords(2) Or randomNumber1 = strWords(3)`

Comment: yes, ... working, thanks.

Comment: The syntax should actually be `If strwords.Contains(randomNumber) Then`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Even better, but it doesn't educate the OP on this common syntax error.